# Append using dataframe.to_csv() while conserving column order

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, dictionary

I am trying to use df.to_csv() to append data to a csv. I would like to use an elegant code to use that, however an issue occurs. From time to time, I happened to get dictionary with keys with different order

```
import pandas as pd

# Simplified version of my function
def save_to_csv(dictionary, index):
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=[index])
    header = index == 0
    df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', header=header)

# I run some function, I get dict 'dict' => I want to save it into csv file
id = 0
dict = {'col_name_1': 1, 'col_name_2': 2, 'col_name_3': 3}
save_to_csv(dict, id)

# I run some function a second time, I get dict 'dict' => I want to append it into csv file
id = 1
dict = {'col_name_2': 2, 'col_name_3': 3, 'col_name_1': 1}
save_to_csv(dict, id)

# etc ...
```

I get

```
,col_name_1,col_name_2,col_name_3
0,1,2,3
1,2,3,1
```

Instead of

```
,col_name_1,col_name_2,col_name_3
0,1,2,3
1,1,2,3
```

I would like to use this function for an extended period of time, so I would like to avoids hacks and have more of a clean/robust solution if possible

If you have some idea that would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: IMHO, the only bullet proof way is to pass the columns as a list: `cols = ['col_name_1', 'col_name_2', 'col_name_3']` then `save_to_csv(dict, id, cols)` and finally `df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=[index], columns=cols)`. Alternatively, you could sort the column names: `df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=[index], columns=sorted(dictionary.keys()))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from @Serge Ballesta that I'll use for this project

```
def save_to_csv(dictionary, index):
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=[index])
    header = index == 0
    df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', header=header, columns=sorted(dictionary.keys()))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find order of the keys that you want to write in the csv file based on the first dict:

```
dict = {'col_name_1': 1, 'col_name_2': 2, 'col_name_3': 3} 
key_list = [key for key in dict.keys()]

save_to_csv(dict, id)
```

Now, you can sort other dictionary keys based on `key_list` and save to csv file:

```
dict2 = {'col_name_2': 2, 'col_name_3': 3, 'col_name_1': 1}
d = {}
In [1735]: for k in key_list: 
      ...:     if k in dict2: 
      ...:         d[k] = dict2[k] 
      ...:                         

In [1736]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[1736]: {'col_name_1': 1, 'col_name_2': 2, 'col_name_3': 3}

save_to_csv(d, id)
```

Same can be done in a loop for all dicts that you have. This will ensure that the order of columns remains same for the dicts you write in CSV.

Comment: I like your answer, however since I may not run the different appends at the same execution, I can't just save the keys into a variable. I think I'll go with the 'cols=sorted(dictionary.keys())' since the column may not change for the specific experiment, but I don't want to hardcode, in the case I do other experiments

Comment: Yep, just understood that, I thought that the build-in .to_csv would match the column directly
Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Sure, glad to help.